# geo point kibana elasticsearch not showing up on tilemap

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to view my geojson on any sort of map in Kibana. 
My original data is a geo polygon with an array of coordinates.
From my understanding, ElasticSearch/Kibana can't visualize geo shapes, so I'm trying to make a coordinate a geopoint so that I can view it on a tilemap.

Is this possible? I've tried to create a couple different mappings. My most current one won't let me index data to it. Any better approaches? (In an ideal world I could plot a polygon...though I don't think Kibana supports this). I am using version 5.3

Original Data (replacing actual values with long and lat):

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat],
                [long,lat]
            ]
        ]
    },
```

This is the mapping elasticsearch defaults to when I index my json:

```
{
  "indexname" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
          "geometry" : {
            "properties" : {
              "coordinates" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
```

This is the attempt I just tried to fix the mapping (however, this approach does not take to any indexed data:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/indexname" -d "{\"mappings\" : {\"my_type\" : {\"properties\" : {\"geometry\" : {\"type\":\"geo_point\"}}}}}"
```

If I try this command it shows up in kibana, but when I try to run a tilemap, the map just disappears, so I'm assuming it is not getting the correct data:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/indexname" -d "{\"mappings\" : {\"my_type\" : {\"properties\" : {\"coordinates\" : {\"type\":\"geo_point\"}}}}}"
```

**EDIT**

No success. I tried:

kibana-plugin install file:///kibana-5.3.0-windows-x86/kibana-5.3.0-windows-x86/plugins/enhanced-tilemap-v2017-03-17-5.2.2/kibana/enhanced_tilemap

```
Attempting to transfer from file:///kibana-5.3.0-windows-x86/kibana-5.3.0-windows-x86/plugins/enhanced-tilemap-v2017-03-17-5.2.2/kibana/enhanced_tilemap
Transferring unknown number of bytes
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read"
```

kibana-plugin install http://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/enhanced_tilemap/enhanced_tilemap-5.2.2.zip

```
Attempting to transfer from http://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/enhanced_tilemap/enhanced_tilemap-5.2.2.zip
Attempting to transfer from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/http://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/enhanced_tilemap/enhanced_tilemap-5.2.2.zip/http://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana-plugins/enhanced_tilemap/enhanced_tilemap-5.2.2.zip-5.3.0.zip
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next [kibana plugin](https://github.com/nreese/enhanced_tilemap) allow you visualize polygons.

If you using kibana 5.3, the plugin installation not support install operation above 5.2
You can do one of to option:

1) open issue in plugin github

2) clone the plugin, extract the zip file to plugin directory vin kibana home,
cd to the plugin that you download and type bower install, restart kibana

Comment: Any idea on how to install. None of my commands on windows cmd are working for this.

Comment: Before type the command you need to cd to kibana home directory, did you do that? Which error you got?

Comment: I was in the bin directory. Should I be in the plugin directory or just the kibana home one?

Comment: thanks! looks like it won't work because I have kibana 5.3.0 and it throws a disabled error because it expected kibana version 5.2.2 even with the bower install

Comment: how should I do my mapping? It still does not work with the way I have above

Comment: Did you succeed to install the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have plugin successfully installed, but no luck quite yet figuring out the mapping to get my points actually there

Comment: Restart kibana and navigate to localhist: 5601, go to visualisation screen, do yo see new type of visualisation?